# Cyclical server-side forwards detected when user clicks on VF page button

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I have a VF page with an action defined at page level.  I have it there because I need to issue some DML statements and the controller and getter/setter don't allow DML statements. That works fine, the problems lies with the action on a commandbutton.  When the user clicks the button and the code ApexPages.currentPage().getContent().toString() is executed, the above error is returned.  This seems odd in that I am not changing the PageReference anywhere.  Salesforce seems to have an issue with two actions happening on the same page.

VF page:

```
  <apex:form id="form" >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!SendEmail}" value="Post Processing" html-button="" style="display: inline;" reRender="none" oncomplete="return false;" />
  </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your page action method `SendEmail` is returning a `PageReference` that points to the page you are currently on.

Check these two links below:

[Visualforce redirect error "Cyclical server-side forwards detected"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274940/visualforce-redirect-error-cyclical-server-side-forwards-detected)

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098xUIAQ